# How to build a navbar that scales with site growth

Tags: html

I have a navbar, and in it right now I have links to various blogs on my site. I have that same markup throughout my site on all pages.

Here is the thing, when I start growing my site, how do I *scale* something like this? Right now, I have been going to each and every html page, and doing a copy/paste anytime I need a new link to it or something similar.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: what backend framework are you using? is each blog post stored in a db etc. will be useful to know all this as there is many possible solutions to fo this

Comment: @brendanmorrison I built it all myself, just using bootstrap and uploaded via FTP through a subsidiary company of go daddy. That is to say, there is no DB currently. I am guessing I set those links as varchars in a DB and ref that in a navbar, is that the right track at all?

Comment: Yes that's one possibility, I would keep each link as a varchar as well as possibly a title that you want to display for each blog post that would be displayed in the nav bar. then you could build your nav bar dynamicaly each time using a scripting language such as php, python, perl, nodejs etc. Im not sure if node.js will be supported by godaddy but undoubtedly the other would be.

Comment: @brendanmorrison Awesome, thanks for the starting point. If you wanna make that as an answer I will accept it

Comment: ... you could also write the script such that each time a new blog is made you call it once and it would modify your nav. bar so that everything within the site remains static. .. and sure i will do that in a minute, if you need help with how to set-up the scripting i'd be glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so a s per the comment's above there is a slew of ways to go about doing this. One possibility, would be to keep each link as a varchar as well as possibly a title that you want to display for each blog post that would be displayed in the nav bar. then you could build your nav bar dynamicaly each time using a scripting language such as php, python, perl, nodejs etc. Im not sure if node.js will be supported by godaddy but undoubtedly the other would be. The approach you take will be a personal choice based on if you control when user upload content (like an administrator) or if uploads can happen freely. if you plan for uploads to happen freely you will most likely want a dynamic approach, However if You plan to have an administrator to oversee each new entry a static approach could be used and called to regenerate the nav. bar each time a new post is made available. Again, if you need some help getting this started you know where to find me! 
-best of luck